# How to troubleshoot index forbidden by Options directive error

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I am seeing the title message in the error log where I am trying to list files in a directory. I know it has to do with no index file in the driectory, but I just need to list files. I have this line in my httpd.conf file:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
```

Can someone suggest a way to enable file listing in a directory. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for other occurrences of the `Options` keyword, and take note of where they are. There's probably one somewhere in a matching `<Directory>` configuration block. `grep -Ri Options /etc/httpd` may be of help.

It's recommended to only allow `Indexes` in directories where you actually intend to allow directory listings, so it may be a good idea to add your own `<Directory>` block.

Comment: Thanks for reply. will check it out and post back.

Comment: I am confused as to what I should be looking for. I am using pleask and have multiple domains on server. When I run the line you suggested I am getting options appearing for all domains. Here is an example: /etc/httpd/conf/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/domain.co.uk.conf:  Options +Indexes
should i not be looking at httpd.conf? Thanks

Comment: I have no knowledge of Plesk, sorry. I recommend that you ask on a Plesk-specific forum. `https.conf` is server-wide, domain-specific files can override it. How Plesk handles these domain-specific files I don't know.